# How to use PostScript Type 1 font in Inkscape Linux?

Tags: fonts

I am trying to use the font msbm10.pfb given by https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/amsfonts/pfb (which is a PostScript Type 1 font by the file command) in (flatpak) Inkscape in Linux. Trying to install the font with the KDE font manager apparently worked the same as installing any other font (considering that apparently feedback is broken in my install). But when open Inskscape the font does not appear neither by Euler neither by the name msbm10 at difference of normally when installing a True Type Font or a Open Type that it does appear with the name in the KDE Font manager.

Comment: Does installing OTF or TTF fonts work in your flatpak inkscape? This might be an issue of either 1. Inkscape in your version not supporting Postscript Fonts (these are getting kind of rare in desktop usage), or 2. Flatpak isolating system fonts and fonts that a flatpak can see.  Or, of course 3. both.

Comment: @MarcusMüller OTF or TTF fonts work. Note that I am always installing user wide my fonts

Comment: Ok, if manually installed OTF fonts work, then the problem is that your inkscape doesn't support Type1 fonts. My guess is that someone already converted the amsfont type1 fonts to TTF or OTF, have you checked for these?

Comment: Do you have `.pfm` file in the same directory as `.pfb`? AFAIK you may need both of them.

Comment: @MarcusMüller is correct : "Pango has dropped support for bitmap fonts (and type 1 fonts) with Pango 1.44" (quoted from https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Text_Rendering_Notes#General_Comments )

Comment: @RomeoNinov No, I have no

Comment: Before install have `.pfb` and `.pfm` in the same directory. Of course the rest of rendering software should support Type1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to use PostScript Type 1 font in Inkscape Linux?

You can't! As @MC68020 [figured out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/753624/how-to-use-postscript-type-1-font-in-inkscape-linux#comment1434297_753624),

> Pango has dropped support for bitmap fonts (and type 1 fonts) with Pango 1.44

<sup>[source](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Text_Rendering_Notes#General_Comments)</sup>

In other words, you'll need a different font format.

It seems [someone has converted the AMS Type1 fonts to OpenType](https://github.com/Happypig375/AMSFonts-Ttf-Otf), so that should work. [Second source](https://github.com/Firestar-Reimu/AMSFonts-OTF/tree/main/amsfonts-otf) for such converted fonts.

Comment: Hm, I have very bad experience with converted fonts....

Comment: @RomeoNinov well, font systems are different, and for example converting a MetaFont package to TrueType is going to lose some information, capabilities. However, seeing that msbm10 is a double-stroke "blackboard" font, I'd assume the use case here is less the typesetting of paragraphs of text, where things like kerning, ligatures, and other complex text layout features are of no relevance. I mean, MSBM10 is essentially "dingbats" for all characters but A-Z.

Comment: Just to add warning to the people who want to use converted fonts :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov absolutely correct! I forget that this will be found by people with slightly different problems as well!